# assertAll a list of booleans

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

There is a list of pages that can be accessed by a user. The `verifyAccess` has a function that returns true/false depending on which page the user is trying to access.

For example - look for the profile IMG locator on a profile page, the Logout button on the logout page, and so on ...

I am using below imports (JUnit APIs)

```
import org.assertj.core.api.SoftAssertions;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable;
```

Like this

```
List<Boolean> assertList = null;
 for (int i = 0; i < pageList.size(); i++) {
            String pageName = pagesList.get(i);
            assertList = new LinkedList<>();
            assertList.add(accessCheck.verifyAccessToPage(userRole, pageName));
        }
    assertAll((Executable) assertList.stream()); 
}

public boolean verifyAccessToPage(String userRole, String pageName) {
        switch (page) {
            case "Profile page":
                return profilePage.profileImg.isCurrentlyEnabled();
            case "Create(invite) users":
                jobslipMyCompanyPage.clickInviteBtn();
                return logoutPage.logoutBtn.isCurrentlyEnabled();
                    }

}
```

Issue is `assertList` list size is always 1, but `for` loop run 12 times for 12 pages. Also `assertAll` is giving below error `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head cannot be cast to org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Issue is assertList list size is always 1, but for loop run 12 times for 12 pages.

Each run of the for loop initializes the variable `assertList` again. Therefore, it always contains only one element.

To assert each result of `verifyAccessToPage` you could use AssertJ's [SoftAssertions](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#soft-assertions):

```java
import static org.assertj.core.api.SoftAssertions.assertSoftly;

assertSoftly(soft -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < pageList.size(); i++) {
        String pageName = pagesList.get(i);
        boolean accessToPage = verifyAccessToPage(userRole, pageName);
        soft.assertThat(accessToPage).as("access to page %s for role %s", pageName, userRole).isTrue();
    }
});
```

If instead you want to test that no invocation of `verifyAccessToPage` throws an exception, you could change the code to:

```java
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertAll;

List<Executable> assertList = new LinkedList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < pageList.size(); i++) {
    String pageName = pagesList.get(i);
    assertList.add(() -> accessCheck.verifyAccessToPage(userRole, pageName));
}
assertAll(assertList);
```

Comment: It works partially - A scenario when a user with lesser privileges (access) is expected not to have access to the page (a false is expected), but it fails because of the `.isTrue()` function.

Comment: @paul I edited the answer with an example using `assertAll`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following library:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.oneOf;
```

and then assert like this:

```
assertThat(assertList, is(oneOf(expectedBooleanValues)));
```

expectedBooleanValues could be true or false

Comment: I don't want tests to stop if any one assertion fails out of 12. Test should only fail on assertAll.